# What do I override to manage the layout of components in a Delphi composite component?

Tags: delphi, custom-component

I am working on a Delphi component which consists of a panel with some labels and buttons. It can look like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

depending on the setting of a property. Also, the layout of the labels changes depending on the length of the first one.

I have been prototyping this with a TFrame, and doing the layout calculations in the OnPaint method of the frame. What is the right place to do this in a component based on a TPanel? Or, more precisely, in a TCustomAdvPanel, which is what I'm deriving from. Does it work in an override for the Paint method, like so?

```
procedure TDateRangePicker.Paint;
const
  hSpacing = 5;
begin
  if FShowRefresh then
  begin
    btnRefresh.Visible := true;
    btnRefresh.Left := Width - hSpacing - btnRefresh.Width;
    btnClearDates.Left := btnRefresh.Left - hSpacing - btnClearDates.Width;
    btnChooseDates.Left := btnClearDates.Left - hSpacing - btnChooseDates.Width;
  end
  else begin
    btnRefresh.Visible := false;
    btnClearDates.Left := Width - hSpacing - btnClearDates.Width;
    btnChooseDates.Left := btnClearDates.Left - hSpacing - btnChooseDates.Width;
  end;
  lblRangeCaption.Left := hSpacing;
  lblDateRange.Left := lblRangeCaption.Left + lblRangeCaption.Width + hSpacing;
  inherited Paint;
end;
```

Comment: `Paint` is absolutely the wrong place to be doing this - it's for actually **drawing** controls, not for positioning them. (They should be positioned before `Paint` is called by Windows itself.) It's hard to say where you should put it, though, because I don't have `TCustomAdvPanel` and therefore don't have any idea what it descends from or what events it has available.

Comment: `TCustomAdvPanel` is basically a very fancy `TCustomPanel`, for purposes of this discussion. Or at least I feel pretty sure about that.

Comment: Why not use `btnRefresh.Anchors := [akTop,akBottom,akRight];` etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely do not use the `Paint` method to re-position controls. In the worst case this keeps on triggering the `Paint` method again, and again... because, well: due to replacing controls, the panel needs to get repainted. `Paint`, and all equivalents, is only meant for drawing yourself.

On whén to implement your code: this should be done in the setter of the `ShowRefresh` property.

On how to implement your `ShowRefresh` property: of course you can move the controls around like you are doing now. You also might consider using [`Margins`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Margins) (Delphi XE) and aligning the buttons and labels. Then the property setters will become rather simple:

```
type
  TDateRangePicker = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FChooseButton: TButton;
    FClearButton: TButton;
    FRefreshButton: TButton;
    FLabel1: TLabel;
    FLabel2: TLabel;
    function GetLabel1Caption: String;
    function GetRefreshButtonVisible: Boolean;
    procedure SetLabel1Caption(const Value: String);
    procedure SetRefreshButtonVisible(Value: Boolean);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property RefreshButtonVisible: Boolean read GetRefreshButtonVisible
      write SetRefreshButtonVisible default True;
    property Label1Caption: String read GetLabel1Caption
      write SetLabel1Caption;
  end;

...

constructor TDateRangePicker.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FChooseButton := TButton.Create(Self);
  FChooseButton.Caption := 'Choose';
  FChooseButton.Align := alRight;
  FChooseButton.AlignWithMargins := True;
  FChooseButton.Margins.Left := 10;
  FChooseButton.Parent := Self;
  FClearButton := TButton.Create(Self);
  FClearButton.Caption := 'Clear';
  FClearButton.Align := alRight;
  FClearButton.AlignWithMargins := True;
  FClearButton.Margins.Left := 10;
  FClearButton.Parent := Self;
  FRefreshButton := TButton.Create(Self);
  FRefreshButton.Caption := 'Refresh';
  FRefreshButton.Align := alRight;
  FRefreshButton.AlignWithMargins := True;
  FRefreshButton.Margins.Left := 10;
  FRefreshButton.Parent := Self;
  FLabel1 := TLabel.Create(Self);
  FLabel1.Caption := 'Foo caption: ';
  FLabel1.Align := alLeft;
  FLabel1.Layout := tlCenter;
  FLabel1.Parent := Self;
  FLabel2 := TLabel.Create(Self);
  FLabel2.Caption := 'From 03/08/2012 to 06/06/2012';
  FLabel2.Align := alLeft;
  FLabel2.Layout := tlCenter;
  FLabel2.Parent := Self;
end;

function TDateRangePicker.GetLabel1Caption: String;
begin
  Result := FLabel1.Caption;
end;

function TDateRangePicker.GetRefreshButtonVisible: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FRefreshButton.Visible;
end;

procedure TDateRangePicker.SetLabel1Caption(const Value: String);
begin
  FLabel1.Caption := Value;
end;

procedure TDateRangePicker.SetRefreshButtonVisible(Value: Boolean);
begin
  FRefreshButton.Visible := Value;
  FRefreshButton.Left := Width;
end;
```

And the testing routine:

```
procedure TMainForm.TestButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DateRangePicker1.Label1Caption := 'Test: ';
  DateRangePicker1.RefreshButtonVisible := not DateRangePicker1.RefreshButtonVisible;
end;
```

Comment: This is basically the approach I took. Since I wound up abandoning the component for the time being in favor of the `TFrame`-based template, I now have to explicitly set the ShowRefresh property inline when I'm initializing the widget (because the template doesn't have an OnCreate event where I can do it with a default), but I guess you just have to accept that when you're using `TFrame`.

Comment: @wades Indeed, a TFrame has no OnCreate event. You should override the Create constructor instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can **create a property** for TDateRangePicker like :

```
property ShowRefresh:boolean read GetShowRefresh write SetShowRefresh

procedure TDateRangePicker.SetShowRefresh( Value : boolean);
begin
  btnRefresh.Visible := Value;
  // Force autosize after hidding Refresh button
  Autosize := True;
end;
```

So, you have nothing to do during the drawing.

Comment: What is the purpose of setting autosize on the frame after removing the button? The panel hasn't changed size. Other than that, this is the way to go.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera It's to resize the panel if you don't want to have the empty space. I had understand this from your example, but it seems i've misunderstand ;)

Comment: I don't want to resize the panel, I want to move the controls that are on it around.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It shows how to change the visibility of `btnRefresh`, but doesn't show where to show that it changed. (`AutoSize := True;` doesn't reflect anything in the code that was provided - is it something you know about the `TCustomAdvPanel` that isn't in the post?)

Comment: @wades - by using a property you can move your components around and recalculate when the property value is set (you just need to add your code instead of setting `Autosize` here). This way the control doesn't have to do this on every `Paint` cycle.

Answer (score 2):

You set the intial positions when you create the child controls, and then update the positions at the time you need to update them (when changing the property, when the Parent component is resized, etc).  You MUST NOT changing the positions inside the `Paint()` method or `OnPaint` event.

If you are using a modern version of Delphi, you should instead make use of the `Align`, `Margins`, and `AlignWithMargins` properties of the child controls.  That way, you just position the controls one time at the time you create them, and let the VCL do all the hard work of repositioning them automatically when it needs to.